# The Great Depression vs The 2008 Financial Crisis

Tags: macroeconomics

So I'm taking this finance course and my professor keeps talking about how the 2008 financial crisis was worse than the great depression.

I have my doubts so my fellow economists, do you think the 2008 financial crisis was worse than the great depression?

Comment: Why do you have doubts? Is it just an impression, or after looking the available data? You should share them with us, so that your question becomes more focused than it is now

Comment: Please also specify 'worse'. Subjectively I liked the 2008 crisis less than the 1929 one. Then again, I am less than 90 years old.

Answer (score 1):

2008 was a recession. 1929 was a depression. Simple as that. Unemployment rates did not hit 20% in 2008. People were literally starving in 1929. Big difference.